# Turn flat file into relational models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, foreign-keys, relational-database, flat-file

I get flat files once a week that have a few 100k rows. I would like to turn them into a relational model system in Rails since there are about five columns that are fairly static and would make sense for a different model that would then be linked back into the main table as a foreign key.

Is there was a quick way to check if an entry already exists, and if so, look it up and put the foreign key in the main model, and if not, create a new entry in the second model and then reference it in the main model.

I can turn the above paragraph into code but wanted to know if there is a simple 'few lines' Ruby or Rails implementation.

Comment: Have you tried https://github.com/zdennis/activerecord-import/wiki ?

Comment: those two things together sound perfect, `find_or_create` for the checking and the importer for the bulk operations. If you'd like to turn this into a answer I'll accept and upvote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for the sake of merging my comment and @anton-z 's.

You can use [activerecord-import](https://github.com/zdennis/activerecord-import/wiki) for doing bulk operations, and ActiveRecord's [find_or_create_by](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#find-or-create-by) to do the checking.